# A very useful riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Everything is known about me
> From my eating habits to my family
> You can kill my parent and children
> I would not be scared, but I would still run
> I can be malicious, I can be nice
> Bringing a world of hurt, or very cool mice
> Maybe now that you've learned more about me
> You'll start noticing how important I can be
> **What am I?**

Hint:

> My "eating habits" are very unusual,
>  It's more akin to equipment rental.

Comment: Is the phrase "or a very cool mice" intentional, or is there perhaps a typo in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you possibly

> a SOFTWARE PROGRAM (or computer program/software in general)

Everything is known about me

> Assuming one has access to the source code, everything is known about the software.  It's not like an animal or the weather, that can do something unexpected or on its own. Software can only do what it is coded to do.

From my eating habits

> Software's 'eating habits' are to consume input and release output.  This process results in known behavior, based on the coded logic.

to my family

> Software will belong to a family of like software that has a reasonably consistent set of rules/language/compilers, etc.  For example "JAVA", "C#", "COBOL" could be families.  The family is typically documented and well known.

You can kill my parent and children
I would not be scared, but I would still run

> Software can be triggered by a parent process.  Often if you kill that process, it will still run (unless you killed the OS/compiler itself, etc.)
>  Software can spawn child processes.  Often if you kill the children, the software will continue to execute.  In both cases, the software is not scared.

I can be malicious, I can be nice

> Software like viruses or malicious software, for example, are bad.  Software like commercial or non profit sites, for example, can be nice and helpful.

Bringing a world of hurt,

> Malicious software can cause extensive damage to financial systems, personal lives, governments, etc.

or a very cool mice

> Software can be used to create neat things such as a super souped up computer mouse.

Maybe now that you've learned more about me
You'll start noticing how important I can be

> In this day and age, software is quite useful and important for everyday life.

What am I?

> You are a SOFTWARE PROGRAM!

Comment: That is correct! And I was unaware that it was indeed a typo, I will fix this right now.

Comment: Nice wordplay in the riddle! Especially 'run', it had me off track for a few days